# Proper strategy for Redis caching relational data

Tags: caching, join, redis

We have the following use case example:

We have users, stores, friends (relationships between users) and likes. We store these tables in MySQL and as a key-value stores in Redis, in order to read from the Redis cache and not hit the database. Writes are done to both data stores. 
Our app is therefore VERY fast, and scalable since we rarely hit the database for reads. We are using AWS for scalable Redis.
However, we have a problem when a user is logged in and we have to show a list of stores, AND which of his friends like that store. This is a join, and Redis does not support joins directly. We'd like to know what is the best way to store and show this data. Ex: if this should be stored in a Redis table where the key value is "store/user_who likes" and mantained with every write, or maybe have an hourly cron that construct this. Then we can read already stored data or we should construct this join on demand?
We notice that not even Facebook updates this info in realtime, but rather it takes several minutes for a friend to see which of my friends likes a page we have in common.
Thanks in advance for any responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends how important it is to you. Why not store each person's friends as a set, and each store's likes as a set, and then when you need the friends who like a given store, you just take the [SINTER](http://redis.io/commands/SINTER) (set intersection) between the two. Should be fast, and storing friends and store likes as sets will get you a lot of similarly nice operations as well. Not sure how you're currently using Redis cache, but you could use these as a likely cheaper memory replacement as well for getting users' friends, stores' likes, etc...

As for cron, not sure how that would help. Redis is more than fast enough to handle the above sorts of writes. Memory will be your bottleneck first.

Comment: Thanks for the SINTER tip. However, we are using Sorted Sets as it lets us paginate when we need to get a user's firends or liked stores for a user. Would you recommend storing data both as a set and a sorted set and use the appropiate one depending on the circumstance?

Comment: No. Just use ZINTERSTORE then and set some low ttl on the resultant intersection so it's used as cache.

Comment: Ok thanks. We notice ZINTERSTORE is pretty expensive: Time complexity: O(N*K)+O(M*log(M)), but I guess using it it makes more sense than storing data twice.